# Reset session timeout programmatically

Tags: javascript, servlets, session-timeout

In my project I have a requirement where in I want to alert an user with a popup whenever the inactive time is about to hit the session timeout time(For ex:5 mins in advance of session expiry), so that the user can click on continue button and programmatically extend the server session.

What's the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with javascript and coldfusion.

```
<!--- Minutes into MS --->
<cfset sessionTimeout = 2>
<html>

<head>
<title>Timeout Example</title>

<script>
<cfoutput>
var #toScript((sessionTimeout-1)*60*1000,"sTimeout")#
</cfoutput>
setTimeout('sessionWarning()', sTimeout);

function sessionWarning() {
   alert('Hey bonehead, your session is going to time out unless you do something!');
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Taken from http://www.webpronews.com/warn-a-user-about-a-session-timeout-with-javascript-2007-01

Answer (score 0):

see the jquery method - 
http://pure-essence.net/2010/02/14/jquery-session-timeout-countdown/